# problem involving centroid and perpendiculars

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

[image]

in triangle $ABC$, $G$ is the centroid and $L$ is an arbitary line through the centroid.     $K,I,J$ are the foot of the perpendiculars from $A, B, C$

i need to prove that $KA+JC=BI$

how to use the midpoints of the sides and is there any way to use the fact that centroid cut the median in 2:1 ratio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Alternatively, one can prove the statement using the facts you mention. Introduce the midpoint $M$ of $AB$ and its ortogonal projection $N$ onto the line $L$. Since $ABJK$ is a trapezoid $(AK\parallel BJ\perp L)$, it is [well known](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/GeoGebra/MidlineInTrapezoid.shtml) that its midline $MN$ is not only parallel to $AK, BJ$ but also satisfies $2MN=AK+BJ$.

Consider now the similar triangles $\triangle MGN\sim CGI$, and deduce, due to the fact that $CG:GM=2:1$, that $$\frac{CI}{MN}=2\iff CI=2MN=AK+BJ$$

Comment: ok so in general,  the  only condition  is that the three lines must be parallel to each other.  am i right?

Comment: Exactly! Notice that we’re basically exploiting two facts: the midline property in trapezoids, and the $2:1$ ratio (and, of course, that the midpoint of $AB$ lies on the median). It’s enough for the three lines to be parallel :)

Comment: Landed here through the link you shared in the same question asked today :) nice solution! Had same idea seeing the problem.

Answer (score 4):

In any Cartesian coordinatisation of the plane, the centroid of a point set is simply the arithmetic mean. In particular, if $G$ is the origin and $L$ the $x$-axis, $0$ must be the arithmetic mean of the $y$-coordinates of $A,B,C$, i.e. with signed distances $IB+KA+JC=0$. *If $B$ is alone on one side of $L$* then with unsigned distances $IB=KA+JC$.

Comment: Landed here through same question asked on the site today :) really like your answer!